# What is the decision version of independent set?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, decision-problem

I always read that finding an independent set of size $k$ in a graph is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete. However, this only requires looking for all combinations of $k$ vertices and this is a polynomial procedure of order $k$.

I know that we can reduce directly SAT to independent set, with $k$ the number of clauses.

The problem is that I can't grasp correctly, as in 3-COLORING or 3-SAT, the required format to study the complexity of INDEPENDENT SET.

What is the decision version of independent set? And why isn't $k$-independent set in $\mathsf P$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The definition of the decision version of independent set is the following:

Given as input a graph $G = (V,E)$ and an integer $k \in \mathbb{N}$, does there exist a set of pairwise non-adjacent vertices $I \subseteq V$ of size $|I| \geq k$?

The problem is polynomial time solvable if you consider $k$ to be *constant*, i.e., you can solve the problem in time $\mathcal{O}(n^k)$ but we usually take $k$ to be a part of the input.  If you reduce an NP-complete problem to this problem, you will see that the $k$ is indeed unbounded.

Comment: But I don't think this definition is complete. What is the size of the input in this case? the number of vertices? It is possible to have a non-deterministic algorithm that for input graph G and k generates the combinations k,n an this is polynomial. Also, the same can be used to generate a polynomial certificate of the non-existence of an independent set of size k. All the combinations showing that there is at least an edge on each one.

Comment: In 3-coloeing we measure by the size of the graph. In 3-sat by the number of vertices or clauses etc... But here is different...

Comment: We measure the complexity in _both_ size of the graph $G$ and the size of $k$.  We always measure the complexity in the entire input.  In $3$-SAT we measure the size of the encoding of the formula.

Comment: Ok, but the definition you write only claims that you are given an integer k. It does not say anymore, for instance k=f(n) or so...

Comment: @JoseAntonioMartinH No, exactly, but in the worst case it _could_ be, so if you come up with an $n^k$ algorithm, it is potentially $n^n$, which obviously is not polynomial.  If you go through any polytime reductions to this problem you will probably understand it better.

Comment: @Jose: the point is that if $k$ is not a fixed constant but instead can be any positive integer, then there is no fixed polynomial which is an upper bound for the run-time of the brute-force algorithm of checking all $\binom{n}k$ collections of size $k$. No poly-time upper bound means no containment in **P**.

Comment: Given the apparent confusion, I think the answer needs to cover more clearly why $n^k$ is not polynomially bounded in the input size. After all, $k$ is not unbounded; $k \leq n$ is apparent, and we can easily reject instances violating this. It might be enough to note that $|\langle G, k \rangle| = c n^2 + \log n + \log k$, assuming the graph is given as adjacency matrix. Therefore, $n^k$ is (super)exponentially larger than the part of the input encoding $k$, and for $k \in \omega(1)$ it is no longer boundable by a polynomial in the input size (which is in $\Th(n^2)$ for reasonable instances).

Comment: @PålGD: Could you please point out to the algorithm that can solve this decision problem in polynomial time (for a given $k$)?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is $k$ might be very big, say as big as about $n$. Then $n^k$ would be exponentially large.

Comment: I think this is missing the point a bit. The problem isn't that $k$ is "very big", the problem is that it can't be bounded by a constant.

Comment: @Huck: he does say "as big as $n$". Bigness is as bigness does, and it doesn't take much for an exponent in a run-time to be "big".

Answer (score 6):

You should distinguish the following two things.

**Independent Set** (what Pål GD described in his answer)
Instance: A graph *G* and an integer *k*∈ℕ.
Question: Does *G* have an independent set of size *k*?

***k*-Independent Set** (*k*∈ℕ)
Instance: A graph *G*.
Question: Does *G* have an independent set of size *k*?

Note that the latter is not a single problem.  Rather, it is an infinite family of problems: 1-Independent Set, 2-Independent Set, 3-Independent Set, 4-Independent Set, and so on.

Independent Set is NP-complete.  *k*-Independent Set is in P for every *k*∈ℕ.  They are completely different.